# floating a variable number of divs into left/right columns

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I need to be able to take divs and float them either into a left column or a right column based on user input.  So, I don't control the order of the divs in the DOM, meaning that there could be 2 divs float left, followed by 5 divs float right, followed by 10 divs float left, and so on.

here's the example

HTML

```
<div class="left" style="background-color:#D8D8D8;">aa</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#C4BD97;">bb</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#8DB3E2;">dd</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#E5B9B7;">ee</div>
<div class="full" style="background-color:#D7E3BC;">ff</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#CCC1D9;">gg</div>
<div class="left" style="background-color:#FBD5B5;">cc</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#D8D8D8;">hh</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#C4BD97;">ii</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#8DB3E2;">kk</div>
<div class="left" style="background-color:#E5B9B7;">ll</div>
<div class="full" style="background-color:#D7E3BC;">mm</div>
<div class="right" style="background-color:#CCC1D9;">nn</div>
<div class="left" style="background-color:#FBD5B5;">jj</div>
```

CSS

```
.left {float:left;clear:left;}
.right {float:right;clear:right;}
.full {float:none;clear:both;}
```

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nNL2V

In the example I would like to collapse the whitespace between ll and cc so that it appears right below.  The solution has to support IE8 and above.

I should also add that I have thought about doing a floating column approach with a left and right div, but it won't work in my case because of the full width divs using clear:both interspersed between the floating sections.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd do this with with pure CSS, but the JQuery involved would be trivial. It's basically moving `DIV`s into left and right floated containers based on their `left` or `right` class.

A little more JQuery, and you've got columns that are not susceptible to the same resizing issues that the accepted answer has...

**HTML**

```
<div id="src">
    <div class="left" style="background-color:#D8D8D8;">aa</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#C4BD97;">bb</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#8DB3E2;">dd</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#E5B9B7;">ee</div>
    <div class="full" style="background-color:#D7E3BC;">ff</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#CCC1D9;">gg</div>
    <div class="left" style="background-color:#FBD5B5;">cc</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#D8D8D8;">hh</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#C4BD97;">ii</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#8DB3E2;">kk</div>
    <div class="left" style="background-color:#E5B9B7;">ll</div>
    <div class="full" style="background-color:#D7E3BC;">mm</div>
    <div class="right" style="background-color:#CCC1D9;">nn</div>
    <div class="left" style="background-color:#FBD5B5;">jj</div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="dest"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left, .right { width:100%; }
.full { width:100%; clear:both; }
.leftCol { float:left; clear:left; width:50%; }
.rightCol { float:right; clear:right; width:50%; }
```

**JS**

```
var cleared = true;
var left;
var right;
$("#src>.left, #src>.right, #src>.full").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.hasClass("full")) {
        cleared = true;
        $("#dest").append(el);
    } else {
        if(cleared === true) {
            left = $("<div class='leftCol'></div>");
            right = $("<div class='rightCol'></div>");
            $("#dest").append(left).append(right);
            cleared = false;
        }
        if(el.hasClass("left")) {
            left.append(el);
        } else if(el.hasClass("right")) {
            right.append(el);
        }
    }
});
```

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/RcvHW/1/

Comment: I thought about doing the 2 column approach, but it won't work in my case because there can also be full width divs in between the floating divs that will clear:both and then the left and right columns continue afterward. I'll edit the question with this info as well.

Comment: Ok, so considering this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nNL2V/, what you want to do is collapse the whitespace between floated divs that appear between full width divs? (move `ll` right up under `cc`)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: I've edited the question to use your fiddle to better outline the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you assign a `width` to the `.left` divs? If so, you can do this:

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
}

.right {float:right; clear: right;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BsMbQ/2/)

Comment: That looks like it may work.  I'll play with it in the actual app and see what I come up with.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried it with more DIVs, and it didn't play well with the 100% DIVs inbetween.

Comment: I suppose it would work as long as you don't need to specify a 50% width for your DIVs on the right. If you specify a right width, it's susceptible to resize issues. I'm updating my answer with a revised column approach without resizing issues.

Comment: Actually that situation only works if the right divs come before the left divs, if you have all the left divs first then the right divs only float up to the level of the last left div: http://jsfiddle.net/C4t4LystX/BsMbQ/3/